# Dialogflow stability

Tags: dialogflow-es

We have a number of chatbot instances we are testing on Dialogflow, some of which are developmental ones and others which are locked down production instances. We do extensive testing to make sure our responses are consistent and correct on a frequent basis.

We've noticed that even on a locked down instance where we aren't changing anything, the intent and entity responses from Dialogflow on an instance can change over time, and in some cases become incorrect.

This suggests that the underlying training algorithm is changing, and that instances are being auto-trained when such changes are released. Does anyone know if this is the case? If so, are there any suggestions about how to maintain a stable instance?

Comment: there's the option to disable machine learning for the intents

Comment: That isn't really relevant @makerGeek. The assumption with a commercial AI service is that once you train a instance, (unless explicitly stated otherwise) it doesn't change. There isn't much of a point using Dialogflow if you have to turn off machine learning to lock it down, as it just becomes a rules-based system.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same situation. We have turned ML off and auto expansion off because when we go into the entities we sometimes get test data being added in there.

Answer (score -1):

First thing, your intent & entity responses will never change if you have locked down instances unless & until you're asking a valid/relevant question. You keep it as it is for as much time as you want, your instances won't get affected.

Second thing, you have a fear of instances are getting auto-trained. See, there is basic difference between AI & ML. Replying user by understanding the context of what user wants to say is AI, on the contrary, ML comes in picture when you're trying to learn from user says & answer based on that. In api.ai, NLP is using AI & not ML so there is no question of auto-training. Now enable/disable option for ML in api.ai is only for computing threshold of how much percent user entered query matches to user says that you have in intent & not for auto-training.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. We have observed locked down instances changing their responses, this is the reason I posted this in the first place.

Comment: The distinction you are making between AI & ML is also specious, and Dialogflow themselves describe their algorithm as ML not AI (the label is not important though). The system certainly does auto-update in response to new intent data, and we suspect this has occasionally happened when they update algorithms as well.

Comment: & so this what I'm saying, how would it happen to answer different responses when you have trained it for something else? Unless & until you're asking a valid/relevant question, chatbot won't go off-track. You should post few snaps if you'd like us to dig this issue to the root cause. Second thing, we also have locked down instances for more than one & half year working absolutely fine. If this was the case, everybody would have observed it. I would suggest you to move to api.ai support team for this issue.

Comment: ML is a part of AI & I have answered your question as well. They label it as ML cause they are computing threshold only. Nothing else beyond that thing. You can easily test this thing, create a sample agent & have few training responses there in an intent. Try & train it for different user queries & check if it learns. It won't cause they are not at all using Auto-training model. I'd be happy to believe if you can produce official documents which say api.ai uses auto-training.